# Javascript callback ajax explanation needed

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I'm hoping someone can explain this for me.
I have a call to a function with an embedded ajax call:

```
getstuff(indata, function (out1,out2) {
            aaa= out1;
            bbb=out2;
            })
```

and the success function in getstuff looks like this:

```
success: cb
```

When we are done "aaa" is populated with the data and "bbb" is "success" which are what

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

says they should be.
But I'm really not sure how out1 and out2 know they are set. How does the function know out 1 is the data and out2 is the textStatus when these are Input parameters?
I good explanation would go a long way.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are passed inside `$.ajax` to the callback. It's exactly how you already posted, somewhere inside, the callback is called as `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`. `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR` are just variables.

You can give the parameters any name. The function knows that `out1` is `data` because it is the **fist** argument passed to the function, so it associates the name `out1` to it. Similar for `out2`.

Here is a very simple example:

```
function foo(callback) {
    var someData = 'someValue';
    callback(someData);
}

foo(function(someParameterName) {
    console.log(someParameterName);
});
```

The name of the function parameters are not related in any way to the name of the variables that are passed and there is nothing magical about callbacks, they are just functions and they don't work any differently. If you'd see this

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2;

function foo(out1, out2) {
    console.log(out1, out2);
}

foo(a, b);
```

would you wonder why `out1` is `1` and `out2` is `2`?